# Flash of background-color when using jQuery .slideToggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

When I'm using jQuery's .slideToggle I see a flash of the preferred background-color at .primary-navigation, but it's not persistant. It shows the preferred background-color during the animation, but it does not stay that way when the animation is complete. I keep scratching my head, but I can't figure it out. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it? This problem occurs in the latest Chrome, FF and iOS Safari.

**EDIT: Here is a jsFiddle that solved the problem: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeredboxman/T67hH/). Thanks to [scessor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843985/scessor) for the quick reply!**

**HTML:**

```
<header class="banner clearfix">
 <h1 class="alpha">Site Title</h1>
 <nav class="primary-navigation-wrapper">
   <ul class="primary-navigation">
     <li><a href="#" id="current-page">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.banner {
  background-color: blue;
}

.banner h1 {
  padding: 6px;
  float: left;
}

h1.js-toggle-navigation {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.primary-navigation {
  clear: both;
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}

.primary-navigation li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.primary-navigation a {
  padding: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  display: block;
}
```

**jQuery (1.7.2.):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    /* prepend menu icon */
    $('.primary-navigation-wrapper').prepend('<h1 class="js-toggle-navigation">Menu</h1>');

    /* toggle nav */
    $(".js-toggle-navigation").on("click", function(){
      $(".primary-navigation").slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to end the floating of the `li`s. E.g. add a css `overflow: hidden;` to the `ul` with the class *primary-navigation*:

```
.primary-navigation {
  overflow: hidden;
  ...
}
```

Also see [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/jRRm6/1/). (Only for the example I've also added a top margin, without the *Menu* button couldn't be clicked in the jsfiddle caused by the result label.)

Comment: I was just in the proces of making a jsFiddle. I was thinking about overflow to stop the floating. Apparently clearfix isn't working, but overflow: hidden is. I tried overflow: auto, don't ask me why, but it is overflow: hidden. Thank you very much scessor!

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul` contains only floating elements, so it's default height is 0. In normal (not animated) state background isn't visible because of zero height. In animated state jQuery sets explicit height for element, so background is showing. You should add `overflow: hidden` to `.primary-navigation` class in your css to get visible background.